# Copy Month wise folders

Tags: rsync, cp

```
                                       Main_Dir
                                          |
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
          Subdir1                         Subdir2                 Subdir3
             |                              |                        |
 -------------------------          ----------------------       ---------
 |            |           |         |       |            |       |   |   |            
01_Mar_15 02_Mar_15 03_Mar_15   01_Apr_15  02_Apr_15 03_Apr_15  1fo 2fo 3fo
```

i want to copy March sub folders but from 23 to 31 march 2015 and entire APR May folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -r Main_Dir/Subdir1/2[3-9]* Main_Dir/Subdir1/3* Main_Dir/Subdir2/* Main_Dir/Subdir3/* newdir/
```